Need help with alcohol burner and denatured alcohol
I recently bought my first home chemistry kit and the alcohol burner is part of it. my questions are: what should I do with any leftover alcohol in the burner after I finish an expiriment?
after treating the alcohol in the burner is it okay to bring it back into my room (where I keep the chem kit) without worrying about any vapors?
and how should I store the denatured alcohol bottle and how should I handle it to be sure it is safe and I dont fill up my house with flamable vapors

You know, unless you drink it, it's just a very strong alcohol?

If the alcohol lamp has a tight-fitting cap, then there's no issue. If the wick is not covered, then the alcohol will evaporate in a few days, wasting it, but unlikely to be a safety hazard unless stored in a very small, completely unventilated room.

Denatured ethanol is not volatile enough to cause large amounts of vapour build up (even open whiskey bottles don't evaporate quickly). The biggest hazard is spilling a large amount near an open flame.

Denatured alcohol is volatile.  Return unburned to the alcohol container, seal securely. Allow the empty burner to air dry in open ar. What you do not want is the kit box to have an explosive mix in the kit box from evaporating solvents. An old bartender's trick: after the last shot from the whiskey bottle shake it good and light the mouth, VROOM

Once the burner is extinguished, allow it to cool and then empty the unburned alcohol back into its original container. Then, allow the burner to dry fully before storing it again.
